# How to fix Bootloader Bug remotely

Tags: microcontroller, bootloader, bare-metal

Recently, I have integrated a boot loader which can upgrade and fix bugs in application software with .bin file kept in USB flash drive. But I am not sure, what would happen if my boot loader itself encounters some issues, how can I identify the issues and fix them remotely?

Microcontroller: RX62N with 96KB RAM and 512KB Flash
OS: None

Comment: This is question is too broad and not targeted at a technical problem but on system design. I recommend you move it over to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ and ask for Bootloader Update Techniques

Comment: Sure, thanks for directing me to the right place.